# Do "web" stats in Google Search Console include Google shopping queries?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, search, statistics, shopping

Does search type 'Web' in Google Search Console (screenshot 1) include free traffic from Shopping tab (screenshot 2)?

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]